# Table not displaying when using Shiny when adding column descriptions to data table

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I'm trying to figure out how I can include column descriptions to a data table using Shiny. The goal is to have some sort of tooltip/hover over that appears that defines the column for the user. When I try to do this, the data table doesn't display at all. It does display when I only include data table with no column descriptions.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

 original_data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:5,
  Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve"),
  Age = c(25, 30, 28, 22, 29)
)

column_desc <- c(
  "ID" = "Unique identifier",
  "Name" = "Person's name",
  "Age" = "Person's age"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("data_table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  reactive_data <- reactive({
    original_data
  })
  
  output$data_table <- renderDataTable({
    data <- reactive_data()
    datatable(
      data,
      options = list(
        dom = 't',
        columnDefs = list(list(
          targets = "_all",
          searchable = FALSE,
          orderable = FALSE
        ))
      )
    ) %>% 
      formatStyle(
        names(data),
        selector = "th",
        style = sapply(names(data), function(col) {
          sprintf("title: '%s'", column_desc[col])
        })
      )
  })
}
```

Comment: formatStyle changes CSS styles of the datatable, it doiesn't implement tooltips.

Comment: Is there a better way to implement tooltips then?

Comment: take a look at reactable with tippy

Comment: https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DTqTips.html